# About tenses: how can I express an event being held during a week?

Tags: phrase-request

I think "this week" can imply the future, the present, and the past. So I don't know how to express the situation properly. (The situation where a festival is currently going on and it's during this week)

1. This week we have a festival there.
2. This week we are having a festival there.
3. We have been having a festival there from last Monday.

I made these three sentences, but all of them sound odd to me.
Don't #1 and #2 imply future event in a week?
And #3 cannot imply that "a festival is held during this week."

Comment: No, (1) and (2) don't imply the future, but the current week.

Comment: @KateBunting Oh, I see.  Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my earlier comment - Yes, the present tense can refer to the future - *We're having a festival this coming weekend* - but a sentence like *We have a festival this week* would usually be understood to mean that the festival has already started unless otherwise specified (*It starts tomorrow*).

You could say *We've been having a festival here since Monday.* If you say *last Monday* it suggests that you mean the Monday of last week.

Answer (score 0):

I think 1 and 2 mean almost the same case except for 2 mean more active process of description

Comment: Your answer has been flagged as low quality by the system. Could you [edit] it to provide more details, please?